# Python Seaborn dynamic update of heatmap data

Tags: python, matplotlib, animation, seaborn, heatmap

I would like to update dynamically a heatmap made with Seaborn, adding data line one by one.
The sample code below get the basics work done, but instead of updating the heatmap it seems to nest a new one in the previous one.

Thank you in advance for any help/solution you may provide.

```
import numpy as np
np.random.seed(0)
import seaborn as sns
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt


data = np.random.rand(120 ,5900)
data_to_draw = np.zeros(shape=(1,5900))
for i,d in enumerate(data):
    # update data to be drawn
    data_to_draw = np.vstack((data_to_draw, data[i]))
    #keep max 5 rows visible
    if data_to_draw.shape[0]>5:
        data_to_draw = data_to_draw[1:]
    
    ax = sns.heatmap(data_to_draw,cmap="coolwarm")

    plt.draw()
    plt.pause(0.1)
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I re-structured your code in order to exploit [`matplotlib.animation.FuncAnimation`](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.animation.FuncAnimation.html).
In order to avoid drawing a new heatmap and a new colobar in each iteration, it is necessary to specify in which axis draw each of them through `ax` and `cbar_ax` parameters in [`seaborn.heatmap`](https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.heatmap.html).
Moreover, after drawing an heatmap, it is convenient to erase the previous one with `ax.cla()`.

### Complete Code

```
import numpy as np
import seaborn as sns
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.animation import FuncAnimation


np.random.seed(0)

data = np.random.rand(120, 50)
data_to_draw = np.zeros(shape = (1, 50))

def animate(i):
    global data_to_draw
    data_to_draw = np.vstack((data_to_draw, data[i]))
    if data_to_draw.shape[0] > 5:
        data_to_draw = data_to_draw[1:]

    ax.cla()
    sns.heatmap(ax = ax, data = data_to_draw, cmap = "coolwarm", cbar_ax = cbar_ax)


grid_kws = {'width_ratios': (0.9, 0.05), 'wspace': 0.2}
fig, (ax, cbar_ax) = plt.subplots(1, 2, gridspec_kw = grid_kws, figsize = (10, 8))
ani = FuncAnimation(fig = fig, func = animate, frames = 100, interval = 100)

plt.show()
```

[image]

---

If you want to keep your original code structure, you can apply the same principles:

```
import numpy as np

np.random.seed(0)
import seaborn as sns
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

data = np.random.rand(120, 5900)
data_to_draw = np.zeros(shape = (1, 5900))

grid_kws = {'width_ratios': (0.9, 0.05), 'wspace': 0.2}
fig, (ax, cbar_ax) = plt.subplots(1, 2, gridspec_kw = grid_kws, figsize = (10, 8))

for i, d in enumerate(data):
    # update data to be drawn
    data_to_draw = np.vstack((data_to_draw, data[i]))
    # keep max 5 rows visible
    if data_to_draw.shape[0] > 5:
        data_to_draw = data_to_draw[1:]

    sns.heatmap(ax = ax, data = data_to_draw, cmap = "coolwarm", cbar_ax = cbar_ax)

    plt.draw()
    plt.pause(0.1)
```