# Having problems labelling axes in a barplot animation shown on a FigureCanvas

Tags: python, matplotlib, animation, tkinter, plot

I've been using the animation method outlined at [Managing dynamic plotting in matplotlib Animation module](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44985966/managing-dynamic-plotting-in-matplotlib-animation-module/44989063#44989063) to create animations and place them on a tkinter FigureCanvas.

I'm having difficulties animating a sequence of barplots in such a way that the y-axis tickmark labels appear as I want them to. My animation will have 100 frames, each consisting of a barplot using four x-values. The data is stored in a 100-by-4 matrix, whose entries are random and fall between zero and one. Each frame of the animation appears on a FigureCanvas. Below is a summary of what I've done so far, where `Player` is the class defined at the link above.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.figure import Figure
from matplotlib.backends.backend_tkagg import FigureCanvasTkAgg
from tkinter import Tk, TOP, BOTH

root=Tk()
root.geometry('1000x1000')

fig=Figure() 

# Place canvas on figure. Each frame of the animation will place a barplot on the 
#canvas.

canvas = FigureCanvasTkAgg(fig, master=root)
canvas.draw()
canvas.get_tk_widget().pack(side=TOP,fill=BOTH,expand=1)

# Random 100-by-4 matrix, each row of which corresponds to an instant in time. 
M=np.random.rand(100,4)
labels=['a','b','c','d']
num_times=M.shape[0]

def update_bar(i):
    ax=fig.add_subplot(111)
    ax.bar(labels,list(M[i,:]))
    # Want y ticks to be labelled 0, .2, .4, .6, .8 for each frame.
    ax.set_yticks(np.arange(0, 1, step=0.2))


ani = Player(fig, update_bar, maxi=num_times)
root.mainloop()
```

When I play the animation, the y-axis labels turn out to be a mess, because the tick marks are recreated in each frame. (See image, which shows the eighth frame.)

Is there a way for me to set the y-tickmark label at all at once before the animation starts?
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should move the line:

```
ax = fig.add_subplot(111)
```

out of `update_bar` function: you don't need a new `ax` in each iteration.
Then, within `update_bar` function you should add this line:

```
ax.cla()
```

in order to erase the previous plot.
Finally, I suggest to add this line:

```
ax.set_ylim(0, 1)
```

in the `update_bar` function, in order to keep fixed y axis limits.

### Complete Code

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.figure import Figure
from matplotlib.backends.backend_tkagg import FigureCanvasTkAgg
from tkinter import Tk, TOP, BOTH
import matplotlib
from matplotlib.animation import FuncAnimation
import mpl_toolkits.axes_grid1

root=Tk()
root.geometry('1000x1000')

fig=Figure()

# Place canvas on figure. Each frame of the animation will place a barplot on the
#canvas.

canvas = FigureCanvasTkAgg(fig, master=root)
canvas.draw()
canvas.get_tk_widget().pack(side=TOP,fill=BOTH,expand=1)

# Random 100-by-4 matrix, each row of which corresponds to an instant in time.
M=np.random.rand(100,4)
labels=['a','b','c','d']
num_times=M.shape[0]

class Player(FuncAnimation):
    def __init__(self, fig, func, frames=None, init_func=None, fargs=None,
                 save_count=None, mini=0, maxi=100, pos=(0.125, 0.92), **kwargs):
        self.i = 0
        self.min=mini
        self.max=maxi
        self.runs = True
        self.forwards = True
        self.fig = fig
        self.func = func
        self.setup(pos)
        FuncAnimation.__init__(self,self.fig, self.func, frames=self.play(),
                                           init_func=init_func, fargs=fargs,
                                           save_count=save_count, **kwargs )

    def play(self):
        while self.runs:
            self.i = self.i+self.forwards-(not self.forwards)
            if self.i > self.min and self.i < self.max:
                yield self.i
            else:
                self.stop()
                yield self.i

    def start(self):
        self.runs=True
        self.event_source.start()

    def stop(self, event=None):
        self.runs = False
        self.event_source.stop()

    def forward(self, event=None):
        self.forwards = True
        self.start()
    def backward(self, event=None):
        self.forwards = False
        self.start()
    def oneforward(self, event=None):
        self.forwards = True
        self.onestep()
    def onebackward(self, event=None):
        self.forwards = False
        self.onestep()

    def onestep(self):
        if self.i > self.min and self.i < self.max:
            self.i = self.i+self.forwards-(not self.forwards)
        elif self.i == self.min and self.forwards:
            self.i+=1
        elif self.i == self.max and not self.forwards:
            self.i-=1
        self.func(self.i)
        self.fig.canvas.draw_idle()

    def setup(self, pos):
        playerax = self.fig.add_axes([pos[0],pos[1], 0.22, 0.04])
        divider = mpl_toolkits.axes_grid1.make_axes_locatable(playerax)
        bax = divider.append_axes("right", size="80%", pad=0.05)
        sax = divider.append_axes("right", size="80%", pad=0.05)
        fax = divider.append_axes("right", size="80%", pad=0.05)
        ofax = divider.append_axes("right", size="100%", pad=0.05)
        self.button_oneback = matplotlib.widgets.Button(playerax, label=u'$\u29CF$')
        self.button_back = matplotlib.widgets.Button(bax, label=u'$\u25C0$')
        self.button_stop = matplotlib.widgets.Button(sax, label=u'$\u25A0$')
        self.button_forward = matplotlib.widgets.Button(fax, label=u'$\u25B6$')
        self.button_oneforward = matplotlib.widgets.Button(ofax, label=u'$\u29D0$')
        self.button_oneback.on_clicked(self.onebackward)
        self.button_back.on_clicked(self.backward)
        self.button_stop.on_clicked(self.stop)
        self.button_forward.on_clicked(self.forward)
        self.button_oneforward.on_clicked(self.oneforward)

def update_bar(i):
    ax.cla()
    ax.bar(labels,list(M[i,:]))
    # Want y ticks to be labelled 0, .2, .4, .6, .8 for each frame.
    ax.set_yticks(np.arange(0, 1, step=0.2))
    ax.set_ylim(0, 1)


ax = fig.add_subplot(111)
ani = Player(fig, update_bar, maxi=num_times)
root.mainloop()
```

[image]

Comment: Just what I needed. Thanks!

Comment: I'm curious to know, if you don't mind my asking, how I could adapt this idea to a heatmap animation so as to make the colorbar appear fixed from frame to frame. 

Now I have ```M_list``` which is a sequence of 100 4-by-4 matrices, all of whose values fall in [0,1]. I changed def 
```update_bar(i)``` to ```update_matrix``` so that the second line was ```im=ax.imshow(M_list[i])```.  I've tried various things both inside and outside the function and the colorbar tick values appear, but move around from frame to frame. 

Perhaps this question should be posted separately?

Comment: You should create a `cbar_ax` for the colorbar and pass it to `seaborn.heatmap` as well as `ax` parameter. You can take [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62397114/9214357) and [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68860651/9214357) as a reference

Comment: Feel free to leave an upvote if you find any answer useful :-)